# User selection in WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I am displaying data with a structure similar to the folder structure on a disc and I want to filter it. If an item is unselected all items under that one are unselected too. If an item low in the tree is selected, all parents to up to the root are selected. The selection shall result in reloading and displaying the data matching the selected items.

For this I have created a TreeFilter class which is displayed a standard WPF TreeView.
When the selection is changed I want to build a list with selected items in the tree (I will extend the TreeFilter class with an additional property for that)
As the combination of items is fixed I created a static class which returns predefined sets of filters (trees).

I even managed to put the whole thing into a UserControl (I am still relatively new to c# and WPF) to be able to reuse it as I will need it in different parts of the solution. The control has a dependency property to bind the filter tree.

I don’t want to use code behind, as everything is MVVM

My problem is the following: How do I even notice, when an item is selected so I can reflect that change in updating the data? When any of those checkboxes is changed (on/off) I want to update the data-view

Thank you very much for your patience and support!

This is my code:

The TreeFilter class

```
public class DTTreeFilter : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        bool isEnabled;
        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get => isEnabled;

            set
            {
                if (value != this.isEnabled)
                {
                    this.isEnabled = value;
                    if (this.isEnabled == false)
                    {
                        foreach (var child in children)
                        {
                            child.IsEnabled = false;
                        }
                    }
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsEnabled)));
                }
            }

        }

        private bool isExpanded;
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return isExpanded; }

            set
            {
                if (value != isExpanded)
                {
                    isExpanded = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsExpanded));
                }

            }
        }

        private bool isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }

            set
            {
                if (value != isSelected)
                {
                    isSelected = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
                }

            }
        }

        private bool isFilterSelected;
        public bool IsFilterSelected
        {
            get { return isFilterSelected; }

            set
            {
                if (value != isFilterSelected)
                {
                    isFilterSelected = value;

                    if (this.isFilterSelected == false)
                    {
                        foreach (var child in children)
                        {
                            child.IsFilterSelected = false;
                        }
                    }
                    // Filter ein -> alle Eltern einschalten
                    if (this.isFilterSelected == true)
                    {
                        if (this.Parent != null)
                            this.Parent.IsFilterSelected = true;
                    }

                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsFilterSelected));
                }

            }
        }

        public DTTreeFilter Parent { get; set; }

        ObservableCollection<DTTreeFilter> children;
        public ObservableCollection<DTTreeFilter> Children
        {
            get => children;

            set => children = value;
        }

        public static DTTreeFilter Create(string Caption, string Description, DTTreeFilter Parent = null)
        {
            return new DTTreeFilter(Caption, Description, Parent);
        }

        public DTTreeFilter(string Caption, string Description, DTTreeFilter Parent = null)
        {
            children = new ObservableCollection<DTTreeFilter>();

            this.Caption = Caption;
            this.Description = Description;
            this.IsEnabled = true;

            if (Parent != null)
                this.Parent = Parent;
        }

        public void AddChild(DTTreeFilter child)
        {
            child.Parent = this;
            children.Add(child);
            this.IsExpanded = true;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"ToString {this.Caption }";
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
```

The TreeView

```
    <TreeView
        x:Name="trFilter"
        ItemsSource="{Binding FilterList}" >

        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DTTreeFilter}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsFilterSelected}"
                              IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               FontWeight="DemiBold"
                               FontSize="14"
                               />

                    <TextBlock Text=" " />

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Width="250" 
                               FontSize="11"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>

        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
```

The prepared Filterset

```
public static DTTreeFilter GetFilterSetA()
{
    DTTreeFilter rootItem = DTTreeFilter.Create("Root Item", "this is the root item");
    DTTreeFilter childItemA = DTTreeFilter.Create("Child A", "this is child A");
    DTTreeFilter childItemB = DTTreeFilter.Create("Child B", "this is child B");
    rootItem.AddChild(childItemA);
    rootItem.AddChild(childItemB);

    DTTreeFilter childItemA1 = DTTreeFilter.Create("Child A1", "this is child A1");
    DTTreeFilter childItemA2 = DTTreeFilter.Create("Child A1", "this is child A2");
    childItemA.AddChild(childItemA1);
    childItemA.AddChild(childItemA2);

    return rootItem;

}
```

The ViewModel

```
public class TreeFilterTestViewModel
    {

        public virtual ObservableCollection<DTTreeFilter> AllFilters { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DTTreeFilter>();
        


        public TreeFilterTestViewModel()
        {
            AllFilters.Add( DTSystemFilter.GetFilterSetA() );
        }
```

resulting in

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGMkd.png)

Comment: Do you want a distinction between a parent item having some of it's children ticked, and having all of them ticked?

Comment: I want all tems that are selected. Each 'level' is loaded one by one so I need the list of selected items. as shown in the attached image the list should contain Root Item, Child A and Child A1

Comment: I understand that. However there is a flaw in your code - setting ChildA1 as selected will eventually set ChildA2 as selected too. I suggest that you make IsFilterSelected a nullable<bool> and only set an item's children as selected if that item is definitely fully selected. For my take on how to handle this, look at my blog post - http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/

Comment: Selected items will then be a combination of IsFilterSelected == true and IsFilterSelected == null (for items with some children selected)

Comment: Thank you @Peregrine, setting ChildA1 selected does not set ChildA2 selected, the selection mechanism works as intended (I cannot post a video to show it). Selecting an item will only travel up the parent tree and select those.